# RS.exe utility still targets .Net 3.5?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I have installed SQL Server 2016 Standard along with SSRS 2017. I am using rs.exe tool for SSRS reports deployment.

When I try to execute rs.exe from command line, I am prompted to install .Net framework 3.5. While tool works after .Net FW 3.5 is installed - this is not something I want to do.

I have searched for similar questions and found out only this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/334685df-8899-4a53-9513-0b443fc485fe/rsexe-depends-on-net-35-but-sql-server-reporting-services-2017-system-reqs-dont-mention-it?forum=sqlreportingservices.

Also, no .Net framework 3.5 is listed in system requirements for Sql Server 2016 or SSRS 2017 (https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016#hwswr)

So I wanted to ask:

1. Has anyone experienced the same situation? Do you need to actually install old .Net framework(2.0+3.5) to use that tool?
2. Any workarounds?

Comment: I have just hit the same problem and like you have no intention of installing a new (lower) version of the .NET framework.
I wonder if this means that Microsoft are no longer support the RS.exe utility?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you managed to workaround it?

Comment: @Tony_craft sorry, do not have a way to work around. I have written my own C# application capable of deploying reports. This way I don't need to use rs.exe and therefore have dependency on .net 3.5. I think that is the best way so far.

Comment: I do not encounter this on a machine with SQL Server 2019 which does not have .net-3.5 installed, so I assume that means `rs.exe` is finally using .net-4.x in SQL Server 15?